# I can't get Google Apps Script run for my Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I followed the script posted in [Any way to send Gmail auto-response at certain times every week?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90075/any-way-to-send-gmail-auto-response-at-certain-times-every-week/90089#90089). However, my Gmail account didn't reply any message during out of work hours per my current test.

Did I do something wrong or incomplete?

What I have done:

1. Created a script on https://script.google.com/ via copying and pasting.
2. Saved the script and tested it. It worked fine.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPdV9.png)

```
function myFunction() {
  function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([4,5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 9) || (day == 3 && hour >= 17)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("xxxx");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

3. Enabled the Gmail API via the menu "Advanced Google Services"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmxZT.png)
4. Set up a trigger for the script as every 5 mintues.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy27L.png)
5. Sent several test emails from another Gmail account to see if there would be any auto-reply.
6. Didn't manually modify any received emails from another account.

Any hints will be very appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Update: I wonder why the following script itself will result in a "Script function not found: myFunction" error?

```
function autoReply() {
  
  // find calendar event
  var today = new Date();
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today, { search: 'OOF' });
  var unavailableToday = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    
    if(events[i].isAllDayEvent() && events[i].isOwnedByMe()) {
      
      unavailableToday = true;
      break;
      
    }
    
  }
  
  var myEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  
  Logger.log('unavailableToday');
  Logger.log(unavailableToday);
  if(unavailableToday === true) {
    
    // get html message
    var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFilesByName('autoreply.html');
    var htmlbody;
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();

      htmlbody = file.getBlob().getDataAsString('utf8');
      
    }
   
    // get emails
    var interval = 2;
    var date = new Date();
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox !label:autoresponded after:' + timeFrom);
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoresponded");

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (message.getFrom().indexOf(myEmail) < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("no-repl") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("bounce") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("spam") < 0) {
        
        Logger.log("Replied now");
        
        // reply
        threads[i].reply("", {
          htmlBody: htmlbody
        });
        
        // label
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Which made me think MyFunction{} is essential?

Comment: please include your actual code and not images.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post with the code. I replaced the auto-reply part as it contains personal information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to remove the `autoReply()` function outside of `myFunction()` and set the trigger up on `autoReply()`.*

#### More Information:

The code should look like it does in the answer you linked:

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 8) || (day == 4 && hour >= 17)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply("I am out of office. Your email will not seen until Monday morning.");
    }
  }
}
```

***NOT*** like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  function autoReply() {
    var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    if ([5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 8) || (day == 4 && hour >= 17)) {
      var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
      var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].reply("I am out of office. Your email will not seen until Monday morning.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`autoReply()` isn't being called when you call `myFunction()`, only declared.

You will need to edit the code and then re-set up your trigger to run on `autoReply()`.

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp):

> Declared functions are not executed immediately. They are "saved for later use", and will be executed later, when they are invoked (called upon).

#### References:

- [JavaScript Function Definitions - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)

Comment: Thanks. The reason I included myFunction was removing it will result in another script stop running: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/143228 and the error code is "Script function not found: myFunction", so as a coding noob, I thought myFunction{} is mandatory?? @Rafa Guillermo

Comment: Could you have a look at another case I updated too? Or I need to make a new question?

Comment: @AlecSandy In normal circumstances on stack overflow you should accept the answer that answers your question and ask a new question rather than editing your question after answers have been provided. As I said in my answer, however, you need to update your trigger as it is still attempting to run `myFunction()`. Go back to the trigger page and edit the trigger so that under `Choose which function to run` you have selected `autoReply`.

Comment: Thanks again. The reason I listed another one here is because it made me have some wrong understanding of MyFunction{}

Comment: @AlecSandy I suggest having a look through some Apps Script basics, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)'s a link to get you started :)

Comment: Not joking but I did try the page you suggested. However, since I kept MyFuntion{} there, it never succeeded, rofl. Anyway, thank you so much for helping a coding noob, and I will probably create a new question about the format of auto-reply.